# I Dont Understand How zoomToRect Works in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

could somebody explain to me about this code snippet? It is for zooming image in iOS app using Swift, but i dont understand why it is working

```
let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
let w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale
let h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale
let x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0)
let y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0)
let rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

scrollView.zoomToRect(rectToZoomTo, animated: true)
```

as a tribute, this code snippet is from ray wanderlich tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is contained in a scrollView. A scrollView can adjust its viewport by scrolling (duh!) horizontally/vertically and also by "scaling". The code you pasted will use newZoomScale (probably a float?) to zoom in ( values > 1) or zoom out (values < 1) and center the view (w/2 and h/2).

Is that enough explaining? What part do you have trouble understanding particularly?

Comment: i still dont understand how can w and h have bigger value than its bounds? it doesnt make sense if the rect i made is bigger than the bounds size

Comment: Why not? if your w/h is bigger than your bounds you won't see the entire picture and have to pan to see the parts outside of your screen.

Comment: See this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html